# undefined references cygwin with stdcall-fixup

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cygwin

I'm building something using Cygwin 32 bit. It's quite large so it has a couple of header files defined in their own .cpp files. I'm even using a few c++ boost headers, linking them. I'm doing this on x64 Eclipse Luna. The project is comprised of a mix of C and C++ files. Every time I build the project I keep getting undefined references errors, for all functions in the header files, including those from boost, despite me having linked the boost libraries correctly. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to attach a screenshot(doesn't make any sense). But below is a sample of the errors. I have even tried linking using option enable-stdcall-fixup to no avail.

```
./caches.o:caches.cpp:(.text+0x1957): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
./caches.o:caches.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv[__ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv]+0xa2): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
./fscore.o:fscore.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `btree_init()'
```

Please help.

Sincerely, batman

Comment: Not sure about Eclipse and Cygwin, but in g++, you need to provide the linking flag like `-lboost_system` for linker to recognize the corresponding library. I think you probably need the same there.

Comment: oh my! what's wrong with my head. I fixed that with the linking -lboost_filesystem. Plus the issue with other functions, was that I had forgotten to wrap them in an extern C block. I'm mixing c with c++